# regular functions with vanishing derivative are constant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential

Let $p:X\to S$ be an $S$-scheme and let $f:X\to \mathbb A$ be a regular function on $X$. Then $f\in \mathcal O(X)$, and we may apply the universal derivation $d_{X/S}:\mathcal O_X\to \Omega_{X/S}$ to $f$. Is it true that $d(f)=0$ if and only if $f:X\to \mathbb A$ is constant on the fibers of $X\to S$ in the sense that $f$ factors as $X\to S\to \mathbb A$ for some regular function $S\to \mathbb A$ on the scheme $S$? One direction follows because $d_{X/S}$ is the universal $p^{-1}\mathcal O_S$-derivation, but what about the other?

In other words: How does the kernel of $d_{X/S}$ look like?

Comment: Here’s one obstruction: consider the map $\operatorname{Spec}{L} \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec}{K}$ corresponding to a finite separable extension. Then the universal derivation is zero, but there are more regular functions on the source than on the range.

Comment: Okay! Thank you for the counterexample :)

Comment: I don’t know if the (local?) existence of unramified morphisms is the only obstruction, though.

Comment: I think $df=0$ should only imply $f$ is locally constant. For instance if $S$ is a point and $X$ is disconnected.

Comment: @JakeLevinson Right!

Comment: @JakeLevinson It does not even imply the local constantness if the base is of char p, e.g. $d(T^p)=0$ in $\mathbb F_p[T]$.